# How can i add smartyBc to slim framework

Tags: php, templates, frameworks, smarty, slim

I am writing a simple slim app and would like to write raw php mixed with smarty syntax but I keep getting the following error.

```
Syntax error in template "./templates/application/header.tpl" on line 106 "{php}" unknown tag "php"
```

if I change my tpl file to `{include_php}` like this

```
  {include_php}
  <?php echo 'home ' ?>
  {/include_php}
```

I get the following error ,

```
Type: SmartyException
Message: {include_php} is deprecated, use SmartyBC class to enable
File: /home/ramza/apps/php/company/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_include_php.php
Line: 52
```

My slim *index.php* is below :

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'vendor/php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php'; 
require_once('Smarty/SmartyBC.class.php');

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg) {
    $cfg->set_model_directory('models');
    $cfg->set_connections(array(
        'development' => 'mysql://root:@localhost/xxx'
    ));
});



require 'models/OcMember.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Smarty()
));


$view = $app->view();
$view->parserDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . 'Smarty';
$view->parserCompileDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/compiled';
$view->parserCacheDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';

$view->parserExtensions = array(
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/slim/views/Slim/Views/SmartyPlugins',
);

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie(array(
    'expires' => '20 minutes',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
    'httponly' => false,
    'name' => 'slim_session',
    'secret' => '1e12350dc6629a44df6b6771b6cb0cabd153aadc91f6af2697d371294296f69866b7c729a58b82108770ab02b087fda821af4533fe85b8115504ed9084055d77',
    'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
    'cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
)));

$authenticate = function ($app) {
    return function () use ($app) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['company_id'])) {
            $_SESSION['urlRedirect'] = $app->request()->getPathInfo();
            $app->flash('error', 'Login required');
            $app->redirect('/company/login');
        }
    };
};


$app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', function() use ($app) { 
   $current_company = null;
   if (isset($_SESSION['company_id'])) {
      $current_company = Company::find($_SESSION['company_id']);
   }
   $app->view()->setData('current_company', $current_company);
});

require 'app/controllers/before_filters.php';
require 'app/controllers/members.php';
require 'app/controllers/login.php';
require 'app/controllers/registration.php';



#require 'app/controllers/category_menu.php';


$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix PHP with Smarty so you should do what you need in PHP and assign value to Smarty. Then you won't need to use {php} tag at all. Smarty is for displaying data and mixing php with Smarty makes that using Smarty doesn't make much sense.

However if you really need to use php tag in Smarty template you should change:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Smarty()
));
```

into

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\SmartyBC()
));
```

but I really don't recommend using php inside Smarty templates

***EDIT - SMARTYBC VIEW DOESN't EXISTS IN SLIM FRAMEWORK SO WE HAVE TO CREATE IT***

Although I've never used Slim framework I've decided to look further. As SmartyBC doesn't exists in Slim views, we have to manually create it.

In the Slim\Views directory you have to create SmartyBC.php file with content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Slim - a micro PHP 5 framework
 *
 * @author      Josh Lockhart
 * @author      Andrew Smith
 * @link        http://www.slimframework.com
 * @copyright   2013 Josh Lockhart
 * @version     0.1.2
 * @package     SlimViews
 *
 * MIT LICENSE
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
 * a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
 * "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
 * without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
 * distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
 * permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
 * the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
 * OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
 * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
namespace Slim\Views;

/**
 * SmartyView
 *
 * The SmartyView is a custom View class that renders templates using the Smarty
 * template language (http://www.smarty.net).
 *
 * Two fields that you, the developer, will need to change are:
 * - parserDirectory
 * - parserCompileDirectory
 * - parserCacheDirectory
 *
 * @package Slim
 * @author  Jose da Silva <http://josedasilva.net>
 */
class SmartyBC extends \Slim\View
{
    /**
     * @var string The path to the Smarty code directory WITHOUT the trailing slash
     */
    public $parserDirectory = null;

    /**
     * @var string The path to the Smarty compiled templates folder WITHOUT the trailing slash
     */
    public $parserCompileDirectory = null;

    /**
     * @var string The path to the Smarty cache folder WITHOUT the trailing slash
     */
    public $parserCacheDirectory = null;

    /**
     * @var SmartyExtensions The Smarty extensions directory you want to load plugins from
     */
    public $parserExtensions = array();

    /**
     * @var parserInstance persistent instance of the Parser object.
     */
    private $parserInstance = null;

    /**
     * Render Template
     *
     * This method will output the rendered template content
     *
     * @param string $template The path to the template, relative to the  templates directory.
     * @param null $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($template, $data = null)
    {
        $parser = $this->getInstance();
        $parser->assign($this->all());

        return $parser->fetch($template, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Creates new Smarty object instance if it doesn't already exist, and returns it.
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException If Smarty lib directory does not exist
     * @return \Smarty Instance
     */
    public function getInstance()
    {
        if (! ($this->parserInstance instanceof \SmartyBC)) {
            if (!class_exists('\SmartyBC')) {
                if (!is_dir($this->parserDirectory)) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot set the SmartyBC lib directory : ' . $this->parserDirectory . '. Directory does not exist.');
                }
                require_once $this->parserDirectory . '/SmartyBC.class.php';
            }

            $this->parserInstance = new \SmartyBC();
            $this->parserInstance->template_dir = $this->getTemplatesDirectory();
            if ($this->parserExtensions) {
                $this->parserInstance->addPluginsDir($this->parserExtensions);
            }
            if ($this->parserCompileDirectory) {
                $this->parserInstance->compile_dir  = $this->parserCompileDirectory;
            }
            if ($this->parserCacheDirectory) {
                $this->parserInstance->cache_dir  = $this->parserCacheDirectory;
            }
        }

        return $this->parserInstance;
    }
}
```

In fact you simple have to copy content from Smarty.php View and change all Smarty to SmartyBC. That's it!

The index.php should look like:

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();


$app = new \Slim\Slim(array (
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\SmartyBC()
)
);

$view = $app->view();
$view->parserDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/smarty';
$view->parserCompileDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/compiled';
$view->parserCacheDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';
$view->setTemplatesDirectory(dirname(__FILE__) . '/smarty/templates');


$app->get(
    '/',
    function () use ($app) {
        $app->render('index.tpl', array('test' => 'User'));     
    }
);


$app->post(
    '/post',
    function () {
        echo 'This is a POST route';
    }
);

$app->put(
    '/put',
    function () {
        echo 'This is a PUT route';
    }
);

$app->patch('/patch', function () {
    echo 'This is a PATCH route';
});

$app->delete(
    '/delete',
    function () {
        echo 'This is a DELETE route';
    }
);

$app->run();
```

You don't have to include here manually SmartyBC.class.php as you did in your code. Of course this is only sample and minimal code (used from Slim Framework and added Smarty view).

Template file:

```
{$test}, hello world and {php} echo "hello world from php"; {/php}
```

Output is:

```
User, hello world and hello world from php
```

so exactly what you wanted to achieve.

However I remind you that's not the best way to mix your PHP with templates. Even in Smarty documentation you can read:

> {php} tags are deprecated from Smarty, and should not be used. Put
>   your PHP logic in PHP scripts or plugin functions instead.

Comment: i tried this and it did not work, looks like SmartyBc is not included in slim views

Comment: I've added complete solution to my answer

Comment: i am yet to try it. i will soon try it out wen i get on my dev machine